# Laravel error with return type of function

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have some test functions in Laravel 7:

```
    <?php

namespace Tests\Feature;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ReadThreadsTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {

        parent::setUp();

        $this->thread = factory('App\Thread')->create();
    }

    public function test_a_user_can_view_all_threads()
    {

        $response = $this->get('/threads');

        $response->assertSee($this->thread->title);
    }
```

When I run phpunit, I get :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Tests\Feature\ReadThreadsTest::setUp() must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::setUp(): void in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\tests\Feature\ReadThreadsTest.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61
PHP   3. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:163
PHP   4. PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:171
PHP   5. PHPUnit\Util\Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:929
PHP   6. PHPUnit\Util\Configuration->getTestSuite() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Configuration.php:881
PHP   7. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFiles() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Configuration.php:1005
PHP   8. PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->addTestFile() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:452
PHP   9. PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::checkAndLoad() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php:354
PHP  10. PHPUnit\Util\FileLoader::load() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\FileLoader.php:47
PHP  11. include_once() C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\FileLoader.php:59

Fatal error: Declaration of Tests\Feature\ReadThreadsTest::setUp() must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::setUp(): void in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\tests\Feature\ReadThreadsTest.php on line 9
```

I am doing something wrong with parent::setUp, but what? I tried adding : void(), but that only change the error to:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in c:\xampp\htdocs\forum\tests\Feature\ReadThreadsTest.php
```

Any advice?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop the parenthesis from :void(), and instead use :void
Hopefully this works for you?

```
 public function setUp():void
    {

        parent::setUp();

        $this->thread = factory('App\Thread')->create();
    }
```

If not, you should track down the TestCase file being extended and examine the setUp() method there to understand what is different about your override of it.